# Travel from France to Saint Louis, do I need to pick up my luggage when transiting in the US?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, luggage

I need to travel from Paris CDG (first flight Air France, 2nd flight Delta, both cies are sky team) to Saint louis missouri via Minneapolis. During the connectiong flight from international to Domestic), Do I need to pick-up my luggage in minneapolis and immediately check-in for domestic flight, or will my luggage will go direclty to Saint-louis. If yes, is it convenient in Minneapolis (I have only 1H25 minutes stop?

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate but I can't find it.